# Get closest row approximately

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

TableTest

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
 5     6     7     8
 12    6     5     6
 2     3.5   6     1
```

And I want to find the closest row with this: 4, 5.75, 7.2, 6
One human can find it (Row 1 is answer), But How can I write a query for Computer to find it?

Comment: Can you explain the logic, why Row 1 is your answer? If we can explain the logic in plain text then we can definitely write SQL query.

Comment: I can write the query by Abs | (4-5) + (5.75-6) + (7.2-7) + (8-6) | But I want to find a better way. I don't know that SQL server has the built-in function or not.

Comment: There is no specialized function. What you need to do is not something that occurs frequently/

Comment: How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I will interpret "closest" as "having the minimum sum of absolute differences between table values and provided":

```
select top 1 col1,col2,col3,col4
from yourtable
order by abs(col1-4)+abs(col2-5.75)+abs(col3-7.2)+abs(col4-6) asc
```

Comment: I write a query like this But I have a problem. this query gets wrong if a number over 200. It's ok if numbers are 1,2,3,4,... But It gets wrong if one of the numbers is big.

Comment: What do you mean wrong? Please provide the data of this example: the row data, the values you input, what (wrong) result you get, and also the datatypes of the columns.

Comment: My mean is a Big number in small number.

Comment: I understand nothing.

Comment: Yes, I apologize. I find out that maybe this doesn't solve with logically and perhaps it can solve the problem with machine learning.

Answer (score 0):

This will take the row with smallest sum of diffs and if there are more same sum of diffs it will take the one which has smallest maximum diffs of col1, col2, col3, col4. I have added the RowId just to somehow point the right row.

The col1, col2, col3, col4 coluns of AbosluteDiff are not necessary I left them here just for better inspection if you'd want to select them:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    Col1 DECIMAL(10,2),
    Col2 DECIMAL(10,2),
    Col3 DECIMAL(10,2),
    Col4 DECIMAL(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO @table (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
VALUES
(5, 6, 7, 8),
(12, 6, 5, 6),
(2, 3.5, 6, 1);

WITH AbsoluteDiff(RowID, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col1Diff, Col2Diff, Col3Diff, Col4Diff, DiffSum)
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) 
    ,Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, abs(Col1-4), abs(Col2-5.75), abs(Col3-7.2), abs(Col4-6), abs(Col1-4)+abs(Col2-5.75)+abs(Col3-7.2)+abs(Col4-6)
    FROM @table
)
SELECT TOP 1 RowID
FROM AbsoluteDiff
ORDER BY DiffSum ASC, CASE
                        WHEN Col1Diff >= Col2Diff AND Col1Diff >= Col3Diff AND Col1Diff >= Col4Diff THEN Col1Diff
                        WHEN Col2Diff >= Col1Diff AND Col2Diff >= Col3Diff AND Col2Diff >= Col4Diff THEN Col2Diff
                        WHEN Col3Diff >= Col1Diff AND Col3Diff >= Col2Diff AND Col3Diff >= Col4Diff THEN Col3Diff
                        ELSE Col4Diff
                    END ASC
```